# написать get запрос с возможностью фильтрации по полям

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

В поле запроса получаю данные по `@RequestParam`,

```java
    @GetMapping(value = "/get_transactions_by_comment_and_amount")
    public List<TransactionDto> getTransactionsByCommentAndAmount(@RequestParam(value = "comment", required = false) String comment,
                                                                  @RequestParam(value = "amount", required = false) Long amount) {
        return transactionService.getTransactionsFilteredByCommentAndAmount(comment, amount);
    }
```

Интересует сам запрос в БД

```java
public interface TransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transaction, Long> {
        List<Transaction> findTransactionsByCommentAndAmount(String comment, Long amount);
}
```

В моем случе запрос с AND или OR не подходит.
При наличии обоих параметров, фильтрация должна производиться по обоим. При наличии одного параметра - фильтрация по одному, при отсутствии входящих параметров - получение всех записей.

Comment: Вы можете сделать 3 запроса вместо одного (по одному эндпоинту для каждого).

Comment: Запрос может принимать неограниченное количество параметров. Поэтому такой мапинг вряд ли удачный. К тому же если потребуется добавить ещё один параметр в будущем, то придется перекомпилироуать все классы.

Comment: Для фильтрации можно использовать спецификации и критерии. Если найду время сегодня, то напишу ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Еще один вариант, это использовать спецификации. Они позволяют динамически конструировать предикаты.

Сначала расширяем наш репозиторий от `JpaSpecificationExecutor`:

```
public interface TransactionRepository
   extends JpaRepository<Transaction, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Transaction> { }
```

Далее определяем базовые предикаты (это можно сделать в любом классе или интерфейсе, в том же `TransactionRepository`):

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;


...
static Specification<Transaction> hasComment(String comment) {
    return (transaction, cq, cb) -> { 
        if (comment == null) {
            return cb.isTrue(cb.literal(true));
        } else {
            return cb.equal(transaction.get("comment"), comment);
        }
    }
}

static Specification<Transaction> hasAmount(Long amount) {
    return (transaction, cq, cb) -> { 
        if (amount == null) {
            return cb.isTrue(cb.literal(true));
        } else {
            return cb.equal(transaction.get("amount"), amount);
        }
    } 
}
```

Теперь в месте вызова можно делать так:

```
import static org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification.where;
...
transactionRepository.findAll(where(hasComment(comment)));
// или
transactionRepository.findAll(where(hasComment(comment)).and(hasAmount(amount)));
```

В данном случае, логика обработки `null` находится внутри `hasComment` и `hasAmount`, но ее можно вынести и наружу, чтоб этим занимался клиент `transactionRepository` и строил спецификацию динамически:

```
static Specification<Transaction> hasComment(String comment) {
    return (transaction, cq, cb) -> cb.equal(transaction.get("comment"), comment);
}

static Specification<Transaction> hasAmount(Long amount) {
    return (transaction, cq, cb) -> cb.equal(transaction.get("amount"), amount);
        }
    } 
}

...
Specification<Transaction> txFilter = someInitialFilter;
if (comment != null) {
   txFilter = txFilter.and(hasComment(comment));
}
if (amount != null) {
   txFilter = txFilter.and(hasAmount(amount));
}
transactionRepository.findAll(txFilter);
```

Answer (score 1):

Тебе нужно добавить отдельный метод с кастомным @Query

```
public interface TransactionRepository extends 
JpaRepository<Transaction, Long> {

    @Query("""
           SELECT t FROM Transaction t WHERE
              (:comment is null or t.comment = :comment) and
              (:amount is null or t.amount = :amount)
           """)
    List<Transaction> findAllByFilter(String comment, Long amount);
}
```

Comment: в таком случае у вас будет фильтрация значений, где _comment is null_, а нужно, чтобы он вообще не учитывался

Comment: @ulxanxv вы упустили, что в запросе на `is null` проверяется не поле в базе, а входящий параметр, так что запрос функционально рабочий. Однако обычно у таких запросов проблема с производительностью, нужно тестировать на репрезентативных данных.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно написать свою собственную реализацию метода и самому проверять пришедшие поля на *null*

**Интерфейс**

```
public interface TransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transaction, Long>, TransactionRepositoryCustom {
}
```

**Свой собственный интерфейс**

```
public interface TransactionRepositoryCustom {

    List<Transaction> findTransactionsByCommentAndAmount(String comment, Long amount);

}
```

**Реализация**

```
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TransactionRepositoryImpl implements TransactionRepositoryCustom {

    private final static String COMMENT_FIELD_NAME = "comment";
    private final static String AMOUNT_FIELD_NAME = "amount";

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<Transaction> findTransactionsByCommentAndAmount(String comment, Long amount) {
        final CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        final CriteriaQuery<Transaction> cq = cb.createQuery(Transaction.class);

        Root<Transaction> root = cq.from(Transaction.class);
        addEqualPredicate(cb, root, COMMENT_FIELD_NAME, comment);
        addEqualPredicate(cb, root, AMOUNT_FIELD_NAME, amount);

        final TypedQuery<Transaction> query = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    private void addEqualPredicate(CriteriaBuilder cb, Root<Transaction> root, String name, Object value) {
        if (value != null) {
            cb.equal(root.get(name), value);
        }
    }

}
```

**Использование**

```
@Autowired
private TransactionRepository transactionRepository;
```